# Rails j Query section_tag Current Value not resetting to defaults

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, integer, html-select

The following  [code](https://jsfiddle.net/s1gu3n5q/8/) is working correctly apart from the  case of  CurrentMaxValue is 10 the options will only give 10 regardless of input value

one other problem is that it will allow option of 10 despite  CurrentMaxValue being lower than 10 (when second option box is filled with a different value the first then defaults to the remaining quantity)

Code works correctly whilst using fiddle however it does not work when copied into application. 
any suggestions ?

cart item model

```
class CreateCartItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :cart_items do |t|
      t.references :cart, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :train_class, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :passenger, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.integer :passenger_qty
      t.integer :male
      t.integer :female
      t.decimal :unit_price
      t.decimal :total_price
      t.string  :outbound

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

view

```
<div class="female-male-options">
     <div class="female-box">
       <%= f.label (t "reservations.female_passengers"), {:class => 'form-container-item-label'} %>
       <%= f.select(:female, @travelers, {selected: @travelers_select}, { id: 'female'}) %>
      </div>
      <div class="male-box">
          <%= f.label (t "reservations.male_passengers"), {:class => 'form-container-item-label'} %>
           <%= f.select(:male, @travelers, {selected: @travelers_select}, { id: 'male'}) %>
       </div>
  </div>
```

its controller

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    ...
    @travelers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    @travelers_select = params[:travelers]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with adding

```
> parseInt()
```

to MaxValue.